Is Earth's iron core kind of like a white dwarf?
Because Earth's iron core has iron atoms not bonded to one another but in a lattice where there is a sea of electrons and there are ionized iron atoms holding back from gravitational collapse of the planet. So is Earth's iron core degenerate and like a white dwarf but far less extreme due to the lower gravity and pressures involved.
Isn't a metal basically like a white dwarf to some extent, so is Earth's iron core more degenerate than metal on the surface?

No, it is more like a liquid, that’s all.

What about Earth's inner core?

No more than any other metal. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas "Some key examples are the behaviour of charge carriers in a metal, nucleons in an atomic nucleus, neutrons in a neutron star, and electrons in a white dwarf. [...] the delocalized electrons in a metal can be derived from the Fermi gas".


Is Earth's iron core kind of like a white dwarf ?

No. Firstly a white dwarf is made up of a core of carbon and oxygen surrounded by a shell of hydrogen and helium, whereas the Earth's core is mainly iron and nickel.
Secondly a white dwarf is supported by electron degeneracy pressure whereas the Earth's core is supported by mechanical forces.
Thirdly, they have very different densities. A white dwarf has a mass comparable to the Sun's compressed into a volume comparable to the Earth's. It has a density of between $10^4$ and $10^7$ grammes per cubic centimetre whereas the Earth's core has a density of about $13$ grammes per cubic centimetre. If the Earth's core were as dense as a white dwarf then gravity at the surface of the Earth would be much higher than it is.

Don’t metals also have a sea of electrons like white dwarfs?

@RoghanArun Yes, but a white dwarf is far, far denser than the Earth's core. A white dwarf has a density of between $10^4$ and $10^7$ grammes per cubic centimetre;  the earth's core has a density of about $13$ grammes per cubic centimetre.

But like they are similar except for the fact that white dwarf is just a more extreme form of the Earth's core rather than completely different properties. It is just the Earth's core material but more denser and higher gravity and doesn't need to be made of iron in order to act like a metal. So is a white dwarf basically a really dense metal?

@RoghanArun A white dwarf is made up of hydrogen and helium. The Earth's core is mainly iron and nickel. They are not at all similar.

White Dwarfs can't be made of hydrogen because they would explode if they were made of hydrogen. There are only helium white dwarfs and carbon/oxygen white dwarfs.

But Graphene kind of does what white dwarfs do?

A white dwarf can be thought of as a truly huge atom - the matter has degenerated due to the extreme energies and pressures of undergoing gravitational collapse, and the individual atoms have merged to form a single homogeneous mass of protons and neutrons. Our core is not composed of degenerate matter - the iron is still composed of separate atoms, with distinct nuclei.
